# Issue compressing sass with django_compressor

Tags: css, django, sass, django-compressor

I'm having an issue integrating `sass` with `Django` using `django_compressor`

The following is the error that results:

```
UncompressableFileError at /
'sass/example.scss' isn't accessible via COMPRESS_URL ('static') and can't be compressed
```

From the template, this results in the error above -

```
{% load compressor %}

{% compress css inline %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/x-sass" href="sass/example.scss"/>
{% endcompress %}
```

Interestingly enough, compression works if I do so inline sass styling, which makes me wonder if the issue has something to do with how I'm linking resources.

Inline **works** -

```
{% load compressor %}

{% compress css inline %}
  <style type="text/x-sass">
    $font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
    $primary-color: #333;

    body {
      font: 100% $font-stack;
      color: $primary-color;
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
{% endcompress %}
```

What seems to be the problem here?

These are my settings -

```
COMPRESS_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
COMPRESS_URL = STATIC_URL
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/coffeescript', 'coffee --compile --stdio'),
    ('text/x-sass', 'sass {infile} {outfile}'),
    ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

I think the issue is that I'm not sure how to set the value for `href`? I wanted to use `{{ static <foo> }}` but it returns the same error. I understand that to include variables you need to use `COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT`, but not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a syntax error in your `sass` file. Are you sure that all mixins are accessible when this is a separate file? You could also comment most of the code out in the file you are trying to compress to see if a simple minimal file compresses correctly.